# Nested parallelism with scikit learn models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nested, ipython-parallel

I want to to do nested parallelism with scikit learn logisticregressionCV inside a for loop:

```
for i in range(0,10):
    logisticregressionCV(n_jobs=-1)
```

I want to parallelize the for loop as well.

I read a lot of post but I couldn't understand much.
one of the post is [this](https://tomaugspurger.github.io/distributed-joblib.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601026/easy-way-to-use-parallel-options-of-scikit-learn-functions-on-hpc).

NOTE: This 'for' loop is not for cross-validation. 'i' can be thought of another dataset obtained from another set of commands not mentioned here i.e i have 10 different datasets and i compute logistic regression for each dataset parallelly.

Please help! have been stuck on this problem for the past 2 days!

Answer (score 1):

- First of all it's not clear why do you need this loop at all. Instead of having this loop just pass the `cv=10` parameter.
- Using parameter `n_jobs=-1` already takes care of running this job in parallel on all available CPU cores.

Comment: hi, this 'for' loop is not for cross-validation, you can think 'i' as another set of data obtained from another set of commands(not mentioned here),i.e there are 10 set of data and I pick one dataset and use logistic regression on it(which itself is parallelised ). I want to parallelise this for loop so that logistic regression is computed for all 10 datasets simultaneously and NOT SEQUENTIALLY.

Comment: @Aakashsaboo,  can you elaborate? What are you trying to do? Why and how are are you going to use `LogisticRegressionCV` for different pieces of data? What would it bring you? And how are you going to merge results?